# Как удалить файлы старше одного месяца?

Tags: windows, bat

Необходимо удалить файлы, старше одного месяца, но необходимо удалять те, которые созданы больше месяца назад, к примеру, файл может быть изменен сегодня, но создан более месяца назад, скрипт должен удалить этот файл, нужно использовать.bat

Comment: Переведите, пожалуйста, Ваш вопрос на русский язык.

Comment: Необходимо удалить файлы, старше одного месяца, но необходимо удалять те, которые созданы больше месяца назад, к примеру, файл может быть изменен сегодня, но создан более месяца назад, скрипт должен удалить этот файл, нужно использовать.bat

Comment: Какая версия OS?

Comment: Это такие эфемерные сущности... Файл может быть создан сегодня, а изменен в прошлом году. Удалять?

Answer (score 3):

В системах Vista и новее, идет утилита `forfiles`, которая позволяет перебрать все файлы по заданным критериям

```
forfiles /p . /s /m *.* /d -31 /c "cmd /c del @file"
```

Данная команда удалит (`cmd /c del @file`) все файлы (`/m *.*`) из текущего каталога (`/p .`), старше, чем 31 день `/d -31`

Для WinXP можно использовать `forfiles.exe` из новых систем.

Второй способ - парсить вывод команды `dir`